# How to add links to related posts on the current post page PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql

Im quite new to php and sql and Im trying to build a news site and im really stuck on trying to display a list of links to posts related to the current post being displayed,here is the code for the topics page

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT
            topic_id,
            topic_subject,
            topic_image,
            topic_content
        FROM
            topics
        WHERE
            topics.topic_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$result = mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<h3>' . $row['topic_subject'] . '<h3>
          <p>' . $row['topic_content'] . '</p>
          <p>' . $row['topic_image'] . '</p>';
}
?>
```

And here is the table from the database im using

```
CREATE TABLE topics (
topic_id        INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
topic_subject       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
topic_content       TEXT NOT NULL,
topic_date      DATETIME NOT NULL,
topic_cat       INT(8) NOT NULL,
topic_by        INT(8) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (topic_id)
) TYPE=INNODB;
```

If at all possible could someone give me the MYSQL and PHP for this
Do ye recommend I add a new field to the database called Tags and use that in tandom with the topic_subject
Any help would be really appreciated
This is my first question on SO
Thanks again guys

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a tags field in the table so the articles you retrieve are really related to the current article.

Another options would be to include articles in the same category.

If you want to have more control over what is displayed as related articles, setting a list or related articles in at the time you are writing an article would be a better approach, as the related content might be updated later.

Here's the code I used:

```
$parameters = array();
$content = '<p>Lorem ispum dolor sit amet.</p><p>{relatedcontent ids="1,2,3,4"}</p>';
if (strpos($content, 'relatedcontent') !== false) {
    $pluginPattern = '#{relatedcontent\s*(.*?)}#s';
    preg_match_all($pluginPattern, $content, $matches);
    if ($pluginCount = count($matches[0])) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $pluginCount; $i++) {
            $parameterPattern = '#(\w+)=\"(.*)\"#s';
            preg_match_all($parameterPattern, $matches[0][$i], $params);
            $parametersCount = count($params[1]);
            for ($j = 0; $j < $parametersCount; $j++) {
                $parameters[strtolower($params[1][$j])] = $params[2][$j];
            }
        }
    }
}
if (!empty($parameters['ids'])) {
    $ids = explode(',', $parameters['ids']);
    var_dump($ids);
}
```

With this code you can then add more parameters to your 'plugin code' like `{relatedcontent width="500"...display="above"}`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thabks Saul What changes do i need to make to my database and how do i echo the results from your code,im quite new to this

Comment: Hi Trevor! You don't need to do any changes with the above code. Just, at the time you are writing the post include the tag `{relatedcontent}` with the parameters you want, like ids="1,2...7,8,9"}. The code listed above should be ran before you display the content, in which way you could have the $ids array the IDs to the related content you provided. Now you can loop through that array and fetch the contents from your database. Did I make myself clear?